# How to solve align items center issue with IE11

Tags: css

**Context**

I am still a beginner and creating a one-page dashboard for work. Unfortunately we are still forced to use IE11. Somewhere in my CSS there is something stopping a part of my website from centering in IE11 and instead it floats to the left slightly and I cannot figure out the solution

**Research/Possible Solutions**

I had found that setting the flex to something like this may help, but it did not work for me:

```
.example`
{
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;

   /* Center vertically */
   align-items: center;

   /*Center horizontaly */
   justify-content: center;

   /*Center horizontaly ie */
   -ms-flex-pack: center;

    min-height: 220px; 
    height:100px;`
}
```

I had also saw a similar solution to changing my CSS to this also, but I still could not get it working

```
.col-md-10 {
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
max-width: 83.33333%; }
```

**My CSS for items not centering**

```
.col-md-10 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%; }

.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important; }

.align-items-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center !important;
  -ms-flex-align: center !important;
  align-items: center !important; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row d-md-flex no-gutters slider-text align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-10 d-flex align-items-center ftco-animate">
                <div class="text text-center pt-5 mt-md-5">
                 **CONTENT**
```

Any and all help appreciated!

EDIT: MS Edge is also replicating the issue to a lesser extent - Screenshots of each browsers behaviour can be seen here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/c45vB.jpg

Comment: When you use flex, you must set sometime `height` and `width` of children `flex` elements

Comment: hyothetically how/what would that look like in my CSS would that be under .d-flex or align items center?

Comment: Nood more code but you can try `margin: 0 auto` or(and) `min-height`

Answer (score 0):

#### One option is to use [auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) to achieve this.

```css
.example {
    //..vendors...
    display: flex;
}

// center vertically
.align-items-center-v {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

// center horizontally
.align-items-center-h {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

// center both
.align-items-center {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```